# Compile VLCKit on Mac OS 10.11.6

Tags: vlc

I'm trying to compile VLCKit on Mac OS 10.11 following this wiki : https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/

I have clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-bindings/VLCKit.git then open VLCKit.xcodeproj in Xcode 8.0 and finally run "Build Everything".

But build failed with thoses issues :

```
'checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking whether xcrun clang++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether xcrun clang++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... no
checking whether xcrun clang++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++0x... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution configure build/VLCKit.build/Debug/Run\ VLC\ configure.build/Script-63FFDBCD0D2AE2AE0092FC96.sh
(1 failure)
make: *** [build/Debug/VLCKit.framework] Error 65'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I was able to get passed these checks by adding `std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` to the CXX flags exported in `Configure.sh`, so that section looks like this:

```
if test $arch = "x86_64"; then
    export CFLAGS="-m64 -arch x86_64 $optim"
    export CXXFLAGS="-m64 -arch x86_64 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ $optim"
    export OBJCFLAGS="-m64 -arch x86_64 $optim"
    export CPPFLAGS="-m64 -arch x86_64 $optim"
    this_args="--build=x86_64-apple-darwin15 --with-contrib=$VLC_SRC_DIR/contrib/x86_64-apple-darwin15 $this_args"
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$VLC_SRC_DIR/contrib/x86_64-apple-darwin11/lib/pkgconfig
fi
```

Hope that helps!